# css/html framework with structure and usage style similar to java/android layouts?

Tags: css

**Note: if you dont know how android layouts work, or have never seen how java layouts are used, please do NOT answer this question.*

- in android you have `LinearLayout`, which can be `vertical | horizontal`, it can be `fill_parent | wrap_content`, etc - also you can put a Linear|OtherLayouts inside other LinearLayouts and combine them however you like
- also I know GWT has layouts like that, but you cant use them independently of GWT (that I know of... or can you ?)
- also the Qt c++ ide (i forget what its called) has similar layouts in the GUI designer.
- blueprint css, 960.gs, yui, etc, are not exactly similar to the above

(the closest thing I can think of is html tables)

is there something like this for html & css ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would use the `<div>` tag and use stylesheets.  **width=100%** would be similar to fill_parent, wrap_content is the default.  Vertical and horizontal can be achieved by judicious use of **float** and perhaps `<ul><li>` styles.

Comment: I was looking for a premade solution, the equivalent of blueprint/960, perhaps this usage 'pattern' is not very web-appropriate, otherwhise ther probably would be something like this already made by now, or perhaps tables already work perfectly for this

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry, I don't know any myself.